# Is it better to use JSF HTML or JSF Core namespaces with inputText when performing validation?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, namespaces

I need to perform simple form validation using JSF. Looking at different online examples I see two patterns:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" label="name">
    <f:validateRequired />
</h:inputText>
```

...or...

```
<f:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" label="name">
    <f:validateRequired />
</f:inputText>
```

The only difference is the namespace of the inputText tag.  Both solutions seem to work, but which one is "more correct" and what makes it a better choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing `f:inputText`, `inputText` is a part of the `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` namespace and should use the `h` prefix, 
like this: `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"`

Where have you seen the `<f:inputText` anyway ?

The only way that you can use `<f:inputText` is only if you assign the `f` prefix your self instead of the `h` , like this: `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` (but its really not a good idea) better stick to the original `h`